Relation between Fourier series and Schur polynomials
Asked initially at MSE.
I would like to know how to express the Fourier series of a symmetric function, $f(\theta_1,...,\theta_N)$, in terms of Schur polynomials $s_\lambda(x_1,...,x_N)$ in the variables $x_j=e^{i\theta_j}$.
The obvious difficulty is that the Fourier series has negative powers. This might be circumvented by defining the extended alphabet $(x_1,...,x_N,y_1,...,y_N)$, with $y_j=x^{−1}_j$. However, a function which is symmetric in the $\theta$'s is not necessarily symmetric in the extended alphabet.
So, is it possible to articulate some nice relation between Fourier series and Schur polynomials? What about Schur-adjacent polynomials, like Jack's, or characters of the orthogonal groups?
If we see $f$ as a function in the extended alphabet, then it is invariant under the exchange of any pairs, $(x_i,y_i)\leftrightarrow(x_j,y_j)$. If it is even in every argument, then it is also invariant under the exchange of $x_i\leftrightarrow y_i$. So it has hyperoctahedral symmetry. This is also true of orthogonal group characters, so maybe in this case a nice relation exists.

what is the answer for $N=1$ and $f(\theta)=e^{-i\theta}$?

@FedorPetrov $f=s_1(y_1)=y_1$. But that says very little about the general structure, if any.

But is it in terms of $s_\lambda(x_1)$, as required?

@FedorPetrov it is in terms of the extended alphabet, as suggested.

Maybe type BC Schur polynomials? That Weyl group has an extra generator $s_0$ acting by $(s_0 ,f)(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N) = f(x_1^{-1}!!,x_2,\dots,x_N)$.
